# Migrating Auth to Core 2.0: The entity type 'IdentityUserRole<int>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-authentication

I am migrating my app to ASP.Net Core 2.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

In the above article, it has the following mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
    // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
    // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Claims)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Logins)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

It looks fine to me. However, when I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

I get the following error:

> The entity type 'IdentityUserRole' requires a primary key to be
>   defined.

ApplicationUser is defined as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for the roles this user belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<int>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<int>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for the claims this user possesses.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<int>> Claims { get; } = new List<IdentityUserClaim<int>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for this users login accounts.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<int>> Logins { get; } = new List<IdentityUserLogin<int>>();

    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the mapping?

Comment: Can you please share the IdentityUser**Role** class?

Comment: I don't have the code. But here's the doc for it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuserrole-1

Comment: @JonasArcangel Did you end up figuring this out? I'm trying to switch out GUID primary keys to int's. Was able to in 1.1, but can't in 2.0. Think your `ApplicationUser` needs to inherit from `IdentityUser<int>` This [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/780) may help you, gets me close, but no cigar.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.RoleId});
```

Comment: Please also try the following:
`builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.RoleId});`

Comment: IdentityUserRole needs a type argument <__>.